# Looking for simple, continuous differentiable decreasing function example that satisfies several conditions

Tags: calculus

Is there some simple function of $c(s)$
  defined on $s\in[0,1]$
 , which is continuous, differentiable and decreasing in s
  such that $$-\frac{\frac{d\left(c(s)\right)}{ds}}{\frac{c(s)}{s}}>1+\frac{sc(s)}{\int_{s}^{1}c(s)ds}$$
 satisfied at some $s_{0}$
  in [0,1]
 ?

I studied the question again and find that the above question can be simplified as the following:

Is there a continuous, decreasing and differentiable function $c(x)\geq0$
  defined on $x\in[0,1]$
 , such that $$\omega(x)=\frac{x\,c(x)}{\int_{x}^{1}c(t)dt}$$
 is decreasing in $x$ at some $x_{0}\in[0,1]$
 ?

This way, we can view $xc(x)$ as a rectangle area below the curve of $c(x)$ and $\int_{x}^{1}c(t)dt$ another area below $c(x)$ curve. The question is exactly when $x$ increase, the rectangle area decrease faster than the integral area. Is there such a curve?

Comment: what is $\bar s?$

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  We get: 
$$ \omega'(x) = \frac{\left(\int_x^1 c(t)dt\right)[c(x) + xc'(x)] + xc(x)^2}{\left(\int_x^1c(t)dt\right)^2} $$
Suppose we want $\omega'(1/2)<0$.  So we want: 
$$ \left(\int_{1/2}^1 c(t)dt\right)[c(1/2) + (1/2)c'(1/2)] + (1/2)c(1/2)^2 < 0 \quad (Eq *)$$
So just define $c(x)$ to have a very large (negative) derivative at 1/2, but that lasts for a short time only, so the integral $\int_{1/2}^1 c(t)dt$ is still significant. For example fix a small $\delta>0$ and define $c(x)$ so its derivative is: 
$$ c'(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & \mbox{if $x \in [0, 1/2-\delta]$}\\
\mbox{tent(x)} & \mbox{if $x \in [1/2-\delta, 1/2+\delta]$} \\
-1 & \mbox{if $x \in [1/2+\delta, 1]$} 
\end{array}\right. $$ 
where $tent(x)$ is a "tent" function such that $tent(1/2-\delta)=tent(1/2+\delta) = -1$ and $tent(1/2) = -M$ for some large value of $M$. You can choose $\delta$ much smaller than $1/M$ so the affect of the tent does not dramatically change the $c$ values for any of the terms in (Eq *) except for $c'(1/2)$.

For example if $c(0)=10$ and $\delta$ is very small, then $c(x) \approx 10-x$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, whereas $c'(x)=-M$, which is as negative as we like, so (Eq *) is easy to satisfy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very close to my intuition. So basically we need a sharp drop of $c(x)$ at the point $x$, like a almost kink point, right? This is very helpful. Nonetheless, is it possible that we can find one such function which satisfies the conditions not only at one kind of kink point but at a larger range of $x$?

Comment: Since the functions and their derivatives are defined to be continuous, if the condition of (Eq *) holds at $x^*=1/2$, it will also hold for an interval about 1/2. You can play with $M$ and $\delta$ to make the interval bigger or smaller. The @nayrb answer is another possible approach, provided the $\omega(t)$ can be chosen so the solution gives $c(x)\geq 0$ and $c'(x)<0$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: That sounds right. The property should hold at the small interval around the picked $x^{*}$. If the @nayrb approach can deliver a more common (or simpler) solution of $c(x)$ without constructing the sharp drop part of the function, that would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick your $w(x)$ and get your $c(x)$ by solving a differential equation.

Rewrite your expression as

$$\int_x^1 c(t) dt = \frac{1}{w(x)} x c(x)$$

and take a derivative to get

$$-c(x)=(x/w(x)) c'(x) + (x/w(x))' c(x)$$

which can be rewritten as

$$c'(x) + \frac{(x/w(x))'+1}{x/w(x)} c(x) = 0.$$

This is a 1st order linear differential equation and can be solved with an integrating factor.

Comment: Well, you would need to be careful that the resulting ODE solution $c(x)$ satisfies the nonnegative and decreasing properties for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can further write the equation as: $$ c^{'}(x)+\left(w(x)/x+1/x-\frac{w^{'}(x)}{w(x)}\right)c(x)=0.$$ You mean that I can pick any value of $x$, $w(x)$ and $w^{'}(x)<0$ and then solve the ODE? In that case, the inequality will only be satisfied at the picked values, right? Can this be solved without picking specific numbers of  $x$, $w(x)$ and $w^{'}(x)<0$ so that the inequality is satisfied for a range of $x$, or even the entire $x\in[0,1]$? Sorry that I should know this, but my ODE knowledge is like zero. Thanks for your help!